# Opening up Port 80 for MAMP

Tags: cmd, port, mamp

Unable to use MAMP as port 80 is supposedly being used by something else.

[image]

Above image shows that port 80 is already listening but by what? Need help on 'killing' that connection. Perhaps a command that can kill all port 80 connections? Tried unchecking the 'use port 80' command on Skype and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

the last column is the PID of the corresponding program. Find it with `tasklist /fi "PID eq 4"`, kill it with `taskkill /f /pid 4`

Comment: Receiving an error. The process with PID 4 could not be terminated Reason: Access is denied. Any further help? Thanks

Comment: `taskkill /f` did the job for me, `taskkill` alone didn't. (it was Skype too for me). Did it with "run as administrator".

Comment: Still no luck after running as administrator. View screenshot for the details. This is really annoying! https://i.gyazo.com/f1119f3c6573c6ed1722b1ba8d89c7b0.png

Comment: according to your screenshot it's a system service. Seems to be essential to Windows. Windows will prevent it from being killed.

Comment: Right. Any further help would be much obliged